# 'Ruby' way to check for regex match before using captures

Tags: ruby, regex, refactoring

In a Ruby Sinatrat app, I'm looking to retrieve some numbers associated with strings that may or may not be present in my input.  For example: "Cruisers #" might or might not be present, and the # may be any integer.

In addition, where commas would be in normal English number notation (1,000 for one thousand), there will be a period in this notation (1.000 for one thousand).

```
match = /Cruiser\s*([\d.]*)/m.match(report)
match ?
   self.cruiser = match.captures[0].gsub(".", "") :
   self.cruiser = 0
```

Seems like there should be a more compact, 'Ruby'ish way to do this - specifically, I'm looking for a way to combine the regex.match call and the conditional assignment into one statement.  Is this, or any other refactoring, possible here?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem. Updated.

```
report1 = 'Cruiser 23.444.221'
report2 = 'Cruiser'
report3 = ''
report4 = '23/04/2010 Cruiser 23.444.221'

class String
  def cruiser_count; self[/Cruiser\s*[\d.]*/].to_s.scan(/\d+/).join.to_i end
end

p report1.cruiser_count # => 23444221
p report2.cruiser_count # => 0
p report3.cruiser_count # => 0
p report4.cruiser_count # => 23444221
```

Comment: but this wont work if he has to capture the number from a bigger string like "23/04/2010 Cruiser 23.444.221", it gives 0

Comment: @rubyprince Thanks for pointing out the problem. I had the greedy match in the regex wrong. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

```
def get_cruiser(str)
  if str =~ /Cruiser\s*([\d.]*)/m
    $1.gsub(".","")
  else
    0
  end
end

puts get_cruiser("Cruiser 23.444.221")
puts get_cruiser("Crusier")
```

prints:

```
23444221
0
```

Answer (score 0):

The following 1 liner is all you need

```
'1234 Cruiser 1.222'.match(/Cruiser\s*([\d.]*)/).nil? ? 0 : $1.gsub('.', '').to_i
 => 1222
```